Number of permutations that map fixed number of elements between boxes
I would like to count the number of permutations with the following restriction:
I have $N$ objects distributed over $d$ boxes. The boxes are labelled by $a=1,..,d$ and I know the number $n_a$ of objects in each box. Furthermore for each pair of boxes $(a,b)$ I know the number of elements $m_{a\to b}$ that the permutation maps from box $a$ to box $b$. Here obviously $\sum_b m_{a\to b} = \sum_b m_{b\to a} = n_a$.
I believe that the total number of permutations satisfying this constraint is $\frac{\prod_a n_a!^2}{\prod_{a,b} m_{a\to b}!}$.
However, I need to know the number of permutations that have positive (or negative) sign. Can someone help me on this?

Are the objects all labelled (i.e., distinguishable)?

Also, I am confused by the word "permutation" here. A permutation maps objects to objects, not objects to boxes. Do you mean that your permutations map exactly $m_{a\to b}$ many objects from box $a$ to objects from box $b$? If so, it is best to speak of (e.g.) colors, not boxes.

Old answer: (see updated answer below after second separation line)
I misread the question and thought it was about justifying the formula (see, e.g., below).
I suspect the question about signs when all the boxes have size $d$ and the $m_{a\rightarrow b}=1$ could be related to the Alon-Tarsi Conjecture.

For each box $a$ you have to split the corresponding subset by destination box which gives a multinomial factor
$$
\frac{n_a!}{\prod_b m_{a\rightarrow b}!}
$$
for that box $a$.
Then for each box $b$ you have to split the corresponding subset according to provenance box which gives the multinomial factor
$$
\frac{n_b!}{\prod_a m_{a\rightarrow b}!}
$$
for that box $b$.
Finally, for each pipeline $a\rightarrow b$, you have to map individual elements which gives a factor of $m_{a\rightarrow b}!$.
The total count then is
$$
\prod_a\left(\frac{n_a!}{\prod_b m_{a\rightarrow b}!}
\right)
\times
\prod_b\left(\frac{n_b!}{\prod_a m_{a\rightarrow b}!}\right)
\times
\prod_{a,b}m_{a\rightarrow b}!
$$
which simplifies to the given formula.

Updated answer:
If at least one of the boxes is not reduced to a single element, then the number of positive permutations being counted is equal to that of negative ones and is therefore just
$$
\frac{1}{2}\times
\frac{\prod_a n_a!^2}{\prod_{a,b}m_{a\rightarrow b}!}\ .
$$
Indeed, let $S$ be the set of permutations which satisfy the constraints imposed by the $m_{a\rightarrow b}$, and let one of the boxes contain two distinct elements say $i$ and $j$.
Then it is easy to see that the map $S\rightarrow S$, $\sigma\mapsto (i,j)\circ\sigma$ obtained by composing with the transposition $(i,j)$, is a sign reversing involution.
In the case all the boxes are singletons, then the matrix $(m_{a\rightarrow})_{a,b}$ must be a permutation matrix, i.e., $m_{a\rightarrow b}=\mathbf{1}\{b=\sigma(a)\}$ for some unique permutation $\sigma$. Then, $S=\{\sigma\}$ and the number of signed permutations is zero or one according to the sign of $\sigma$.
Finally, I mentioned above a possible connection to the Alon-Tarsi Conjecture. It is there, but fortunately, it is not too close to the present question, so as to render it hopeless.
Consider the element
$$
T=\sum_{\sigma\in S}{\rm sign}(\sigma)\sigma
$$
in the group algebra of the symmetric group $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n]$, with $n=d^2$, in the case where all the $d$ boxes have size $d$, and all the $m_{a\rightarrow b}$ are equal to $1$.
We have an evaluation map ${\rm ev}$ (related to the Frobenius characteristic) which sends a permutation $\sigma$ to the monomial $x^{c(\sigma)}$ where $c(\sigma)$ is the number of cycles of the permutation $\sigma$.
Consider the polynomial
$$
P(x)={\rm ev}(T)\ .
$$
Then the Alon-Tarsi Conjecture is equivalent to the statement that $P(d)\neq 0$ when $d$ is even.
The argument above shows that $P(1)=0$ if $d>1$. With a little bit of diagrammatic algebra, as discussed in MO question
Who invented diagrammatic algebra?
one can also show the vanishing $P(x)=0$, for $x=2,3,\ldots,d-1$.
For other MO posts discussing the Alon-Tarsi Conjecture, see
A closed formula for $\det(\partial/\partial U)^p\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^p U_{i\sigma_j(i)}$
Explicit invariant of tensors nonvanishing on the diagonal
Symmetric polynomial from graphs

It might not be that bad, after all. I think one can make my count bijective, i.e., writing the permutation as a composition of different independent pieces like shuffle permutations, a fixed permutation like we are counting, and also permutations for each pipeline. I didn't check all scenarios but I think there should be as many positive as negative permutations in the end.

Thank you very much, interesting, didn't expect that the number of even and odd permutations is equal unless m is indeed a permutation, but it makes sense. Thank you also for mentioning the connection to the Alon-Tarsi Conjecture (though its the first time I hear about it).

You're welcome. I added more link to posts related to this conjecture.
